# Are existing applications and provisioning profiles affected when resetting devices after renewing an Apple Developer account?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am resetting our devices at the beginning of our new Apple Developer Account term and want to remove most of the existing devices. I want to remove all existing devices and start clean, and then add the devices only as required to ensure we have the most space possible throughout the next year.

My question: After resetting devices, how are existing applications that were built with provisioning profiles including these devices affected? I searched Apple Developer documentation, general Google searching, and through here as well and could not find a direct answer to this question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any application that has already been built with a previous provisioning profile will still run on a device that was included in that profile. But going forward, if you want to run any new versions of the same app on the same device, that device ID will need to be in the updated provisioning profile, which means you will need to re-add it to your developer account.